# How can I fit a table in a page with an long inline math expression inside?

Tags: tables, math-mode, lists, inline, supertabular

I have the problem of making this table fit inside a list in such a way that the long inline math expression can be nicely broken.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{description}
\item [Exercise 2.4] Establish each of the following facts. 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $\vdash \ P \ \rightarrow \ P$
        
        \begin{supertabular}{rll}
            1) & $P \ \rightarrow \ (P \ \rightarrow \ P)$                            & PL$_1$ \\
            2) & $P \ \rightarrow \ [(P \ \rightarrow \ P) \ \rightarrow \ P]$                                 & PL$_1$ \\
            3) & $\{P \ \rightarrow \ [(P \ \rightarrow \ P) \ \rightarrow \ P]\} \ \rightarrow \ \{[P \ \rightarrow \ (P \ \rightarrow \ P )]$      & PL$_2$ \\
            & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$\rightarrow \ (P \ \rightarrow \ P)\}$} & \\
            4) & $[P \rightarrow \ (P \ \rightarrow \ P)] \ \rightarrow \ (P \ \rightarrow \ P)$ & 2, 3, MP \\
            5) & $P \rightarrow P$ & 1, 4, MP \\
        \end{supertabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that I have to manually break the inline math formula, which is not neat in the least. Another problem is that by breaking it that way, all the tables end up with different sizes. I do not mind where do the formulas break, but I want to break in such a way that all the tables have the same size, and preferably, that they have the width of writing space of the page.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on shoving the table to the right, the material can be made to fit all on one line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathrsfs,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem,array,supertabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[wide=0pt]
\item[Exercise 2.4] Establish each of the following facts. 
   \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]
   \item $\vdash \, P \, \to \, P$
   \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    
   \begin{supertabular}{@{}r >{$}l<{$} l@{}}
      1) & P \, \to \, (P \, \to \, P)                               & PL\textsuperscript{1} \\
      2) & P \, \to \, [(P \, \to \, P) \, \to \, P]                 & PL\textsuperscript{1} \\
      3) & \{P \, \to \, [(P \, \to \, P) \, \to \, P]\} \, \to
           \, \{[P \, \to \, (P \, \to \, P )] \to \, (P \, \to \, P)\} & PL\textsuperscript{2} \\
      4) & [P \to \, (P \, \to \, P)] \, \to \, (P \, \to \, P)         & 2, 3, MP \\
      5) & P \to P                                                   & 1, 4, MP \\
   \end{supertabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it! The problem with this is that I will be having longer sentences later on for which this solution will not work.